# touch create body touch destroy body

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am looking at ways to create a body in Box2D with the first touch
and destroy it with a second touch.

To create the body I am using this method:

```
(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];

    if (touch.tapCount > 1) {
        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sprite.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 90)];

        sprite.position = ccp(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);
        sprite.tag = 7;
        [self addChild: sprite];

        b2BodyDef ballBodyDef2;
        ballBodyDef2.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        ballBodyDef2.position.Set(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);
        ballBodyDef2.userData = sprite;

        b2Body *body2 = _world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef2);

        b2CircleShape circle;
        circle.m_radius = 22.0/PTM_RATIO;//(arc4random()*26.0)/PTM_RATIO;

        b2FixtureDef ballShapeDef2;
        ballShapeDef2.shape = &circle;
        ballShapeDef2.density = 1.0f;
        ballShapeDef2.friction = 0.5f;
        ballShapeDef2.restitution = 0.2f;

        body2->CreateFixture(&ballShapeDef2);
    } else {
        b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);

        for (b2Body* b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext()) {
            b2Fixture *bf1 = b->GetFixtureList();
            if (bf1->TestPoint(locationWorld)) {
                CCSprite *tempSprite = (CCSprite *) b->GetUserData();
                if (tempSprite .tag==7) {
                    [self removeChild:tempSprite cleanup:YES];
                    _world->DestroyBody(b);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this method, to create the body, I have to touch the screen 2 times, and then once more to destroy it. What I would need to do so that you tap once to create the body, then tap again to destroy?

Comment: You haven't told us what's wrong with this code. Where do you have a problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

In this way you create body when tap once then tap again to destroy

```
    if (isBodyCreated ==NO)
    {
        isBodyCreated=YES;
        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon.png"];

        sprite.position = ccp(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);
        sprite.tag = 7;
        [self addChild: sprite];

        b2BodyDef ballBodyDef2;
        ballBodyDef2.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        ballBodyDef2.position.Set(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);
        ballBodyDef2.userData = sprite;

        b2Body *body2 = world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef2);

        b2CircleShape circle;
        circle.m_radius = 22.0/PTM_RATIO;//(arc4random()*26.0)/PTM_RATIO;

        b2FixtureDef ballShapeDef2;
        ballShapeDef2.shape = &circle;
        ballShapeDef2.density = 1.0f;
        ballShapeDef2.friction = 0.5f;
        ballShapeDef2.restitution = 0.2f;

        body2->CreateFixture(&ballShapeDef2);
    } 
    else 
    {
        b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);

        for (b2Body* b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext()) 
        {
            b2Fixture *bf1 = b->GetFixtureList();
            if (bf1->TestPoint(locationWorld))
            {
                CCSprite *tempSprite = (CCSprite *) b->GetUserData();
                if (tempSprite .tag==7) 
                {
                    [self removeChild:tempSprite cleanup:YES];
                    world->DestroyBody(b);
                    isBodyCreated=NO;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: strange.
the code suggested by Banu is perfect, but I do not understand why, the simulator is fine, but crashes on the iPhone

Comment: no crashes occur in Iphone.First of all set Bool variable "isBodyCreated" and then set isBodyCreated=NO; in init method.if u Tap the Screen first check is any Body created ,if "isBodyCreated==NO" that means body wasn't create ,so create a body in Touch position,and set BOOL variable to YES.Afterward next tap check "isBodyCreated==NO" condition fails so program goes to else part and test , if we touch in the body ,if yes then remove it

Comment: again thanks.
I had not inserted isBodyCreated inside the init method.
Stupid